# Installing works with easy_install but not pip for dogstatsd-python library

Tags: pip, easy-install

Installing library dogstatsd-python works using easy_install, but does not work using pip (in a virtual environment on Mac OS X)

Using easy_install:

```
$ easy_install dogstatsd-python
... (lot of output)

$ ls -alrt venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ | grep statsd
dogstatsd_python-0.5.2-py2.7.egg
```

Using pip:

```
$ pip install dogstatsd-python
Downloading/unpacking dogstatsd-python
  Downloading dogstatsd-python-0.5.2.tar.gz
  Running setup.py egg_info for package dogstatsd-python

Installing collected packages: dogstatsd-python
  Running setup.py install for dogstatsd-python

Successfully installed dogstatsd-python
Cleaning up...

$ ls -alrt venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/  | grep statsd
statsd.pyc
statsd.py
dogstatsd_python-0.5.2-py2.7.egg-info
```

Pip installed the .egg-info file, and then put the python files directly in the site-packages directory? (Note that the statsd.py file was not installed in any dogstatsd-python directory, but in the site-packages directory itself)

Is this an issue with the library or am I doing something wrong?

I have the following versions installed:

```
distribute 0.7.3
pip 1.4.1
setuptools 12.0.3
```

EDIT:

Here's the issue this is causing. The dogstatsd-python library works with the statsd libray.

```
Using pip:
$ pip install statsd
$ pip install dogstatsd-python

>>> from statsd import statsd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name statsd

Using easy_install:
$ pip install statsd
$ easy_install dogstatsd-python
>>> from statsd import statsd
>>>
```

More info: https://github.com/DataDog/dogstatsd-python

Comment: It looks like a successful install, have you tried using the package in python after a pip install?

Comment: @sedavidw I added more detail with the problem it is causing

Answer (score 0):

`dogstatsd` and `statsd` conflict.  Both end up installing a top-level `statsd` module.  You can install https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dogstatsd-python-fixed/0.5.0 to move `dogstatsd` to a different name:

```
% pip install dogstatsd-python-fixed
% python                                                                                                                   
>>> from dogstatsd import statsd
>>>
```